# CentOS 6 httpd killed by update

Tags: apache, centos, undefined, symbols

Panic Mode commences! I installed updates yesterday.

On restart, httpd yielded:

```
Starting httpd: /usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: `/usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.so.0: undefined symbol: apr_os_uuid_get
```

Running `ldd -r` generates the same message:

```
ldd -r /usr/sbin/httpd
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe82d9000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f121e5fd000)
        libpcre.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre.so.0 (0x00007f121e3d1000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f121e1b1000)
        libaprutil-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x00007f121df8d000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f121dd56000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f121db2d000)
        libdb-4.7.so => /lib64/libdb-4.7.so (0x00007f121d7b9000)
        libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007f121d587000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f121d369000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f121cfd5000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f121cdd1000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f121eae5000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f121cbcc000)
        libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f121c953000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f121c74b000)
undefined symbol: apr_os_uuid_get       (/usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.so.0)
```

Short of downloading apache source, what are the options.

I already did a yum clean all and made sure I'm using only the base repositories. No updates available, yadda.

I'm downloading the apache2 source code while I await the obvious quick-fix answer.

Comment: What does `rpm -q httpd` say? What about `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.so.0`? What about 'rpm -q --whatprovides apr-util`?

Comment: rpm -q httpd: httpd-2.2.15-39.el6.centos.x86_64

Comment: rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.so.0: apr-util-1.3.9-3.el6_0.1.x86_64 (same output for rpm -q --whatprovides apr-util)

Comment: I downloaded/config'ed/built/started Apache 2.2.29, so the panic is reduced a bit. But this is pretty serious: a lot of folks use CentOS 6 for a web server.

Comment: I think the crux of the problem is displayed with: /usr/sbin/httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Oct 16 2014 14:48:21
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)

Comment: You appear to have a 32bit `apr` package installed. See `libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0`. That's probably the problem. What does `rpm -q --qf '%{n}-%{v}-%{r}.%{arch}\n` apr` say? That probably needs to be updated or removed.

Comment: rpm -q --qf '%{n}-%{v}-%{r}.%{arch}\n' apr: apr-1.3.9-5.el6_2.x86_64

Comment: Hm... I wonder if I needed `--dupes` on that command line. Oh well. What does `rpm -qf /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0` say?

Comment: That 32-bit libapr appears to be an artifact from a Tomcat experiment back in July. Has it been that long since Apache rebooted? Solved! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extraneous 32bit version of `libapr` installed. Visible in the following line.

```
libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007f121d587000)
```

You can find out what package owns that file by running `rpm -qf /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0`.

That package might need upgrading (or removal if it is unused).